# Strange problems with Flutter and Hive

Tags: flutter, dart

I experience several problems with Hive database in a Flutter app:

1. **`Hive.initFlutter()` is not working.** I get the following error:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: HiveError: You need to initialize Hive or provide a path to store the box.
```

I tried to call the method with appPath and without, it makes no difference! If I use `Hive.init(appPath)` instead of `Hive.initFlutter()` I do **not get the above exception**! Here the code in the flutter app:
(`Init` is a class with lots of static methods to initialize the application. It is called in the `FutureBuilder` of a splash screen widget. The `setupLocalHiveDatabase()` method is called first to init Hive and open all boxes.)

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // init Hive and open all boxes
  await Init.setupLocalHiveDatabase();

  runApp(MyApp());
}

  static setupLocalHiveDatabase() async {
    print('Setting up hive ...');
    var appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    print('The application directory is: ${appDocDir.path}');
    _setupHive(appDocDir.path);
    print('Open all boxes ...');
    await Hive.openBox<CreditCard>(HiveBoxes.creditCard,
        compactionStrategy: (entries, deletedEntries) => deletedEntries > 10);
    await Hive.openBox<ConfigItem>(HiveBoxes.appConfig,
        compactionStrategy: (entries, deletedEntries) => deletedEntries > 10);
    await Hive.openBox<SupplierOverview>(HiveBoxes.supplier,
        compactionStrategy: (entries, deletedEntries) => deletedEntries > 20);
    await Hive.openBox<SubscriptionOverview>(HiveBoxes.subscription,
        compactionStrategy: (entries, deletedEntries) => deletedEntries > 20);
    await Hive.openBox<BscUserProfile>(HiveBoxes.bscUserProfile,
        compactionStrategy: (entries, deletedEntries) => deletedEntries > 10);
    await Hive.openBox<SyncJob>(HiveBoxes.syncJob,
        compactionStrategy: (entries, deletedEntries) => deletedEntries > 10);
    await Hive.openBox<SyncProtocol>(HiveBoxes.syncProtocol,
        compactionStrategy: (entries, deletedEntries) => deletedEntries > 20);
    await Hive.openBox<ClientDevice>(HiveBoxes.clientDevice,
        compactionStrategy: (entries, deletedEntries) => deletedEntries > 2);
    await Hive.openBox<ClientError>(HiveBoxes.clientError,
        compactionStrategy: (entries, deletedEntries) => deletedEntries > 10);

    print('done.');
  }


  static void _setupHive(String path) async {
    // We initialize Hive and we give it the current path
    print('Initializing Hive databases ...');
    //Hive.init(path);
    await Hive.initFlutter(path);
    print('Registering Hive Adapters...');
    Hive.registerAdapter(ConfigItemAdapter()); // ID 1
    Hive.registerAdapter(CreditCardAdapter()); // ID 2
    Hive.registerAdapter(SubscriptionOverviewAdapter()); // ID 3
    Hive.registerAdapter(SupplierOverviewAdapter()); // ID 4
    Hive.registerAdapter(ClientErrorAdapter()); // ID 5
    Hive.registerAdapter(BscUserProfileAdapter()); //ID 6
    Hive.registerAdapter(SyncJobAdapter()); //ID 7
    Hive.registerAdapter(PersonAdapter()); // ID 8
    Hive.registerAdapter(ContactDataAdapter()); // ID 9
    Hive.registerAdapter(SyncProtocolAdapter()); // ID 10
    Hive.registerAdapter(ClientDeviceAdapter()); // ID 11

    // Enum Types
    Hive.registerAdapter(SyncStatesAdapter()); // ID 101
    Hive.registerAdapter(SyncDirectionsAdapter()); // ID 102
    Hive.registerAdapter(ContractDataObjectTypesAdapter()); // ID 103
    Hive.registerAdapter(OperationResultsAdapter()); // ID 104
    Hive.registerAdapter(PlatformTypesAdapter()); // ID 106

    print('Done with Hive setup.');
  }
```

2. **Data not persisted correctly**

I have the strange situation that data is **empty** after the application is restarted (Hot reload or full restart). Here is the output **just after saving the object**

```
flutter: UserData: BscUserProfile(0031cd3c-5851-403c-9c11-7ea190db5abf, Debug Test User, debug@test.com, , , [])
```

If i do a Hot Reload the data looks as follows:

```
flutter: UserData: BscUserProfile(, , , , , [])
```

The object is in the database but **empty**.

Here is the dart code (it is in the `Init` class as above)

```
  static _setupUser(String userEmail) async {
    var userBox = Hive.box<BscUserProfile>(HiveBoxes.bscUserProfile);
    //await userBox.deleteAll(userBox.keys);
    if (userBox.isEmpty) {
      // create a fake user for testing
      var user = BscUserProfile(
        bscUserEmail: userEmail,
        bscUserDisplayName: 'Debug Test User',
        bscUserId: Uuid().v4().toString(),
      );
      await userBox.put(user.bscUserId, user);
      GetIt.instance.registerSingleton(user);
      for (var user in userBox.values) {
        print('UserData: ${user.toString()}');
      }

      return;
    }
    // dump database
    for (var user in userBox.values) {
      print('UserData: ${user.toString()}');
    }
    var user = userBox.values.firstWhereOrNull((user) => user.bscUserEmail == userEmail);
    if (user != null) {
      GetIt.instance.registerSingleton(user);
      return;
    }
  }
```

If I uncomment the second line to **delete** all objects from the box it correctly jumps into the `(userBox.isEmpty)` and then shows the correct data. After the Reload the database is **not Empty** but shows the empty object!

**3. Updates not working**
Third problem in also in the `Init` class. I persist some device specific data when the application is started. After updating it, the update is **not reflected** in the database after the application is restarted. Here the output of some print statements:

```
flutter: ClientDevice(e5634285-7e46-4eed-8d89-1a9b4cbfb94d, 93C259F6-EBE2-4079-9B99-E542B714B230, iPhone 11 Pro, iPhone, PlatformTypes.iOS, ios, 11.6, 16, en, gala.local, false, 172.16.63.186)
flutter: Device has changed!
flutter: Current device: ClientDevice(e5634285-7e46-4eed-8d89-1a9b4cbfb94d, 93C259F6-EBE2-4079-9B99-E542B714B230, iPhone 11 Pro, iPhone, PlatformTypes.iOS, iOS, 15.0, 16, en, gala.local, false, 172.16.63.186)
flutter: Persisted device: ClientDevice(e5634285-7e46-4eed-8d89-1a9b4cbfb94d, 93C259F6-EBE2-4079-9B99-E542B714B230, iPhone 11 Pro, iPhone, PlatformTypes.iOS, ios, 11.6, 16, en, gala.local, false, 172.16.63.186)
```

Here the **Version** is not updated: **11.6** shows up after a restart, it is then updated with **15.0** but seems not to be persisted.

I do not know it I do something wrong here or if it has problems changing data during initialization or if it is a `Future / async` problem. It is curious. If anybody sees what is going wrong it would be greatly appreciated. (I use AndroidStudio and latest versions of Dart and Flutter)

Answer (score 1):

call it in main without path

like

```
/// main
void main() async {
  /// db init
  await Hive.initFlutter();
....
}
```

i think you can use your calls structure, but you need init `Hive.initFlutter()` without path

Comment: Problem 1) seems to be solved when I write `Hive.initFlutter()` as first line in my `main()` method. No idea what makes the difference, since as mentioned in the message, I tried **with** and **without** path parameter in my `Init` class. *Problems 2. and 3. remain*.

Comment: Solved Problem 2): There was old code in the `BsUserProfileCode` class, the `  @HiveField(0)` numbers where messed up and partially missing. After correcting them it works as expected.